# Google Cloud Run deploy from source with a specific Python version

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running into issues with my type-hinted Python code on Google Cloud Run when deploying from source and believe this to be because Cloud Run is not running my code on Python >= 3.9. Is there a way to set which Python version a cloud run job will be run with when deploying from source?

I've tried creating a .python-version file and setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable, but neither have worked.

Comment: You declare (or install) the version of Python when you build the container. Edit your post and include the Dockerfile and deploy commands. If you are not using a Dockerfile, write one and use that when building the container.

Comment: How do you build your container?